# Authenticating against App Engine from Android app with Federated Login (OpenID)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth, openid

I've followed Nick Johnson's tutorial on [Authenticating against App Engine from Android](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app)

Is there anyway to get the same workflow (no web signin) with Federated Login (even if support is limited to Google Accounts)?

[Edit] *Additional Info*

The current setup includes:

- App Engine's `UserService` configured for federated login (openId..gmail, aol, myspace?,...)
- Facebook (OAuth)
- Twitter (OAuth)

All the authentication types are wrapped in a `UserService`, so I can call `UserService.getCurrentUser()` (Similar to Appengine's UserService, but supports twitter, and facebook).

Accounts can have multiple authentication methods linked together.

So far the clients are all web based, and things are working nicely. **:D**

I'd like to:

1. Add a public Api (for web and native mobile apps),
2. use the Api internally for native mobile apps.

What are the options?

I was thinking of limiting authentication to Google Accounts for the Android App, in hopes of avoiding the web based sign in screen.  Even so it would be nice to support facebook and twitter for the web Api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, OpenID is a browser-based auth standard - it relies on user being directed to external auth page and then back to app page.

You can do this via `WebView` inside a `Dialog` for a smooth user experience. See the [LeanEngine](http://www.lean-engine.com/) open-source project for an example implementation: [server](https://github.com/PeterKnego/LeanEngine-Server/tree/master/lean-server-lib/src/main/java/com/leanengine/server/auth) and [client](https://github.com/PeterKnego/LeanEngine-Android/blob/master/lean-android-lib/src/main/java/com/leanengine/LoginDialog.java). Server is a bit complicated as it supports both Facebook and OpenID login. OpenID only login would be simpler. You basically only need the client example.

However, if you do not need OpenID and are willing to limit your users to Google Account, then you can use [Google ClientLogin API](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html). An [example usage](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=303).

Comment: Is switching back to App Engines default authentication option (Google Accounts API) the only way to use ClientLogin? If I do this I could use a 3rd party library for OpenId.

Comment: LeanEngine look useful~ Does it use AppEngine's UserService? Can it be used for a REST Api?

Comment: Yes it uses UserService when doing OpenID, but not for Facebook auth. Yes, it already has the REST layer which can be extended. Look at the examples, client and server.

Comment: It looks like the LeanToken is used to authenticate against the REST layer.. So the client authenticates once using Oauth/OpenId, gets the lean_token, and from then on it relies solely the lean_token. Is that correct?

Comment: Per-user auth token (that can be expired) is more secure that what most other mobile apps do - have an app secret baked in the app. See parse.com for example.

Answer (score 3):

I have been researching this topic for several weeks now and I finally saw light at the end of the tunnel.  I'm hoping you can at least get a few pointers from my research.  First, I just realized (http://softwareas.com/oauth-openid-youre-barking-up-the-wrong-tree-if-you-think-theyre-the-same-thing)  that OpenID and OAuth are not the same thing, although they could be used in conjunction.  My Google App Engine app is configured with Google Accounts API, and I currently only have an Android client.  I'm a religious follower of Nick Johnson's super famous blog that you mentioned above.  So, I used the AccountManager instance in the Android client to seamless authenticate with my App Engine app, without asking the user for credentials, and without redirecting to a browser/webview, etc.

Just like you want to open up a public API to your GAE app, I also want to expand my client base to have other clients like web-based clients, python APIs, iOS clients, etc, and neither of those have this handy AccountManager.  So, OAuth is the obvious choice.  Here's an article from Ikai Lan of Google App Engine team demonstrating the use of a python client using OAuth to authenticate against a GAE app: http://ikaisays.com/2011/05/26/setting-up-an-oauth-provider-on-google-app-engine/

Funny thing is, I thought that use of Oauth at the client required configuring the GAE app with OpenID/Federated login.  But this is not the case.  So the solution for me, and likely for you too, is simple - on the Android client, use AccountManager per Nick's blog.  And on other clients, use Oauth, and redirect the user to Google Accounts page to enable authentication (see Ikai Lan's article that I talked about in the previous paragraph).

Bottom line for you though is, you can avoid the web-based sign-in on an Android client, but not anywhere else.  You have to authenticate a user at least once, somehow.  Hopefully browser based sign-in happens only the first time, and the browser caches future requests.

Good Luck!

Comment: I have an update after implementing (almost successful) Oauth sign-in from my Android client communicating with my GAE python app.  I used google-java-client-api v1.6 on the Android client (as described here: http://fabiouechi.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-google-oauth-java-client-to.html.  But in order to send app-specific data from my Android client, I discovered that I can't use URL-encoded data.  So I used application/json.  More details in my stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870670/using-google-api-java-client-on-android-a-post-request-does-not-seem-to-authent.

Comment: only problem is that GAE is NOT FREE any more.  google's policy is akin to that of a school gate drug dealer: get the kids hooked for free and then start charging them for it.

Comment: I see the spirit of what you're saying.  But GAE was never free.  They used to charge based on CPU hours used, and now they charge based on Instance hours (similar to how Amazon S3 charges).  So, if you were a CPU intensive application, you'd probably see your charge not change at all.  But the vast majority of applications are very 
I/O intensive, and would have seen an increase in their costs.  From that point of view - yes, GAE had a bait-and-switch approach.  But everybody does it, right?  Cell carriers, DSL, cable providers... gyms (first 3 months free?)