# Google App Engine OpenID Authentication

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm creating a Google App Engine application and have some questions for authentication. I'm going to have users logging in through mobile and web apps, but want them to have more flexibility than just using a Google account.

So if I want the user to be able to sign up and sign in on my own website, would I use OpenID to create this and still be able to use the Google Users API for authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you would use OpenId for that.  See the [App configuration and management](https://developers.google.com/appengine/features/#app_configuration_and_management) section in [Overview of App Engine Features](https://developers.google.com/appengine/features/) and follow the links to whichever server programming language you plan to use.

**Edit**: If you don't want to use authentication provided by Google or an OpenId provider, you can always reinvent that wheel and build an authentication system yourself within your own app.

Comment: Do I need to redirect to a third party site for authentication? I'm looking at this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748502/authenticating-against-app-engine-from-android-app-with-federated-login-openid

Comment: Yes, and the login URL that your application displays includes a continuation URL for the third party login page to use to redirect the browser back to your application after a successful login.

Comment: Oh, so the user would not be able to sign up and sign in on my own website and would require a 3rd party account to use my website? I'm not sure if this is the solution I want then... Thanks.

Comment: The user would be able to sign up and sign in on your website if you manage the accounts and passwords yourself.  Third parties are optional, but they will not give your software access to the passwords of their users.